# Pass number function in azure pipeline dinamically

Tags: azure-data-factory, pipeline

Trying to pass sum or multiply number to subtract from date dynamically in blue pipeline as below:

```
@concat(
    'RANGE:',
    1+((1-1)*(variables('totalcount')/20)),
    ':',
    variables('totalcount'),
    ':50'
)
```

[image]

The above expression says Unrecognized expression: 1+((1-1)*(variables('totalcount')/20))

Comment: `variables('totalcount')` what is the value of this? and what is your expected result?

Comment: The math functions are add, mul, div, etc.  You cannot use the +, *, / literals.  You might have to convert the variable to int or float.  And I think your equation will always return 1 so there may be an error - because 1-1 is zero which is multiplied against the rest of that section.

Comment: @RakeshGovindula, number is 18000, yes, the result is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The math functions in Data Factory are add, mul, div, etc.  You cannot use the *,+,/ literals.  Here is the converted expression

```
@concat(
    'RANGE:',
    string(add(1,mul(sub(1,1),div(int(variables('totalcount')),20)))),
    ':',
    variables('totalcount'),
    ':50'
)
```

which gives the result "RANGE:1:18000:50".  You did not specify the expected result so don't know if that is what you want.  The expression I changed will always result in a value of '1' because of the 1-1 part.